# "No Batteries Available" in KDE battery widget

Tags: kubuntu, kde, battery, chromebook

I have installed Kubuntu 17.10 on my Chromebook via crouton. The problem I'm having is that my battery doesn't show in the battery widget, I haven't had this problem with GNOME, Xfce, or Unity. I'm assuming it's a problem with KDE. When I hover my mouse over the battery widget, it displays a message saying, "No Batteries Available." Does anybody happen to know of a fix to this?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Restarting Plasma helps in my case.

This technique is useful when you're trying to restart the Plasma desktop.

```
kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
```

- The KDE Plasma desktop is d-bus enabled and therefore you can provide the name of the application that runs the Plasma desktop to `kquitapp5` to stop it. In the examples above the name of the application is `plasmashell`.
- The `kstart5` command launches applications with special window properties. In the examples above it just starts the `plasmashell` application which was killed in previous command.

Comment: Can you explain your command line answer a little more (describe each component a few is suffisant). Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1189994/edit) your post.

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me on Kubuntu 19.10. Rebooting did not previously fix the issue, and the `upower` utlity was already installed and the issue was still occurring.

Answer (score 2):

In `~/.config` try renaming `plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` to `plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.bak` and reboot.

Warning: this will reset some of your plasma settings. If it doesn't fix the battery problem, replace the new file with the old one, reboot again and the old settings will be restored.

If this doesn't work, try the answer in ["Battery not present" Dell Inspiron 14-7437 [Kubuntu-14.04]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538737/battery-not-present-dell-inspiron-14-7437-kubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

Comment: I got suddenly the same problem, 2 months after new installation (kubuntu 18.04). I removed this mentioned file and the problem disappeared, but since it messed my settings, I copied the old .bak back and the battery widget still works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and fixed by rebooting.

```
sudo reboot
```